# Using Xceed PropertyGrid How to use a Color

Tags: c#, wpf

Hey I'm using Xceed PropertyGrid and my ModelClass has two properties for Color and Font:

```
public System.Drawing.Font Font 

public System.Drawing.Color Color
```

The propertygrid will display color and font not like i think it should. Font is just a textbox and color too (where font seems to autocomplete the user input: when i write times and press enter it sets the font field to times new roman etc.)

Are my properties just of wrong type or why is it not showing a dialog for font and color (like in paint or word). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The built in editors only support System.Windows.Media.Color/Font, not the System.Drawing ones.

Comment: Anyone sure about it?

Comment: Here in the comments, also mentioned: http://www.broculos.net/2014/03/wpf-how-to-use-propertygrid-to-create.html#.WS5-oWiGNEZ